# Return DateTime as VarChar for use in DataGridView

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, xampp, mariadb

I wrote a simple database-application in Visual studio accessing a small database in XAMPP.

I want to fill a gridview with the contents of a date-field from a database.
The main problem i'm having here is the the CONVERT isnt working (syntax error), but i have the feeling there is a answer thats a lot simpler for the task of simply displaying a date.

Here is the Create of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `lans` (
`l_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`l_datum` DATE NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`l_id`),
UNIQUE INDEX `datum` (`l_datum`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=2;
```

The Query im trying to run:

```
gridViewLans.DataSource = CLanDB.SQLOpen("select CONVERT(varchar,l_datum, 104) from lans").Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

And the function SQLOpen i wrote.

```
public static DataSet SQLOpen(String cSQL) {
    MySqlCommand qCmd = oDB.CreateCommand();
    qCmd.CommandText = cSQL;
    MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(qCmd);
    DataSet set = new DataSet();
    adap.Fill(set);
    return set;
}
```

The error i get:

```
SQL Fehler (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'varchar(100), lans.l_datum, 104) as Lan from lans' at line 1
```

How do i resolve the syntax error?

Comment: why don't you do the query and when you return the dataset bind the datagrid to the set.Tables[0]` once returned also you can format the DataTime field in the datagridview template doing something like this 
`DataFormatString="{0:MM-dd-yyyy}" ` google search how to use the `DataFormatString` property

Comment: Dang, im stupid, it wasn't the showing of the table but rather the adding new entries that didnt work and provoked a malformatted entry, which refused to bind to the gridview.

Comment: "104" smells like Sybase syntax, not MySQL.

Comment: Do not "normalize" dates!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a malformatted entry in the table.
Once i deleted that i could use

```
gridViewLans.DataSource = CLanDB.SQLOpen("select l_datum as LAN from lans").Tables[0];
```

and it worked finely.